# Select2 'None' option

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2 dropdown and I would like to have a 'None' option (with value="") added to the top of the dropdown list.  My drop down is a son call so It's dynamic.

I understand the placeholder and I have that already.  I know that if the user leaves the field blank thats the same thing by what I am getting at is I want it clear that you are selecting 'None'.

I can't see to find this anywhere else.  I tried something like this:

```
        <select class="select required" name="foo" id="bar">
          <option></option>
          <option value="">None</option>
        </select>
```

but that does not work.  The dropdown works great otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `allowClear`

```
$("#select-box").select2({
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: "Search for a movie",
    ...
```

You can also asign the placeholder via `data-placeholder` on the `<option></option>`

Comment: I sort of mentioned that in the question.  I have a placeholder already.  I want an actual selection "None" that passes "" for a value.

Comment: I didn't see any reference to `allowClear`, thought that might help

Comment: Sorry - you are right.  I think you need allowClear for the place holder to work and I think that is what I got my lines crossed.  Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I have my own answer but I will still accept another better solution.  I ended up adding a "" => "None" pair in my json call that feeds this select2.  It works but I think it would still be better to somehow add it locally.